# k8s should traffic goes to master nodes or worker nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

Should traffic from clients (outside world) to service inside k8s comes in through master nodes or worker nodes? and why?

From what i seen so far, docs are always showing LB pools consisting of master nodes instead of worker nodes. is there a reason for this?

in a big bluster, would it be more beneficial to send all traffic to a few designated worker nodes?

for example:
let say my k8s cluster has 2 master nodes, 4 worker nodes, and an external load balancer. most examples out there load balance incoming traffic to the 2 master nodes instead of the 4 worker nodes. why is this? is there a reason in term of efficiency/performance?

please advise. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean the traffic goes through worker nodes or master node? You expose your service in the pods to the outside world via NodePort or LoadBalancer. So who ever hits the LoadBalancer or reach the node on a particular port would be redirected to the corresponding service.

Comment: let say my k8s cluster has 2 master nodes and 4 worker nodes + external load balancer. most examples out there load balance incoming traffic to the 2 master nodes instead of the 4 worker nodes. why is this? is there a reason in term of efficiency/performance? thank you.

Comment: There is no concept of routing traffic to nodes . You route traffic to services on your K8 cluster which then actually distribute the traffic to the corresponding pod running your service. This has no connection to nodes at all. The pods running your service may reside across multiple nodes in the same cluster. So your service would actually loadbalance to the corresponding pods based on the algorithm used. The default is round robin